# Is it useful to have a 0..1 to 0..N here?

Tags: database-design

I came across this example from school.

[image: 0..1 to 0..N example]

Doesn't this imply that you could have something like: *0 messages are answer to 0 messages*?
It confuses me, because wouldn't a *1 to 0 or more messages* suffice?

Comment: I'd be more curious to know how a message could be the answer to more than one other message.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the purpose of this example myself. I noticed it when helping a friend. I just wonder if there in general are use cases for 0..1 to 0..N relationships.